# How to handle not defined variables in Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a a view and several routes to this view (get, post, ...). In this view I am outputting a variable let's call it `$new` that the `Route::post` passes to the view. The `Route::get` doesn't. Now, if i call the `Route::get` I get an error from the view that the variable $new is not defined.

Whats the best practice to handle this? I thought of two options:

1. `<?php isset($new) echo $new; ?>`
2. Or pass the variable empty from the route to the view.

What is the correct way? Are there other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel [Blade templates](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) handle this for you:

```
{{{ $new or 'Default' }}}
```

which is the same code as

```
{{{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}}
```